# New divs not creating from a newly created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove the addcontent button once a new div is created.
Then create new divs from the new addcontent button created inside a new div.

```
<script>
    var i = 1;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addcontent").click(function () {              
            var q = "new-question" + String(i);
            alert(q);                
            $(".question").append('<div class="new-question" id="question' + i + '" name="question' + i + '"><b>Div is created</b><br> This is div text <br> <button id="addcontent">Add content</button></div>').show('slow');
            i++;                                
        });
    });
</script>




<div class="question">
    <button id="addcontent">Add content</button>   
</div>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique in HTML and learn [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: $('#addcontent').remove() respecting what @Satpal said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 <script>
    var i = 1;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click','.addcontent',function(){

        //$(".addcontent").click(function () { 
            if(i==1)
                  $(".question").html('');          
            var q = "new-question" + String(i);
            $(".hide_button").remove();
            alert(q);                
            $(".question").append('<div class="new-question" id="question' + i + '" name="question' + i + '"><b>Div is created</b><br> This is div text <br> <button class="addcontent hide_button">Add content</button></div>').show('slow');

            i++;                                
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="question">
    <button class="addcontent hide_button">Add content</button>   
</div>
```

Comment: When a new div is added, the previous button should be removed. In short, I want a single button in the bottom div. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to have `div` inside `div` questions:

```
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.question').on('click', 'button#addcontent', function () {
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $(this).remove();
        var q = "new-question" + String(i);
        alert(q);
        $parent.append('<div class="new-question" id="question' + i + '" name="question' + i + '"><b>Div is created</b><br> This is div text <br> <button id="addcontent">Add content</button></div>').show('slow');
        i++;          
    });
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gedky77k/)